# v-for loop in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, vuejs2

I am trying to iterate the object using v-for.

```
exampleObject =[a,b,c,d]
Requirement = if a exist in exampleObject, show only a, else show b, c, d.
```

```
 <div v-if="checklist.types">
      <div v-for="type in checklist.types">
         <div v-if="type.Name == 'Module1'">
              show module 1
         </div>
         <div v-else>
             <span>{{type.Name }}</span>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The above shows all values as the condition is checked within For Loop. Is there a way to iterate and check the object at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a computed property that returns an array containing...

1. Only `a` / `Module1` if it exists
2. The entire `exampleObject` / `checklist.types` otherwise

Then you can just iterate that computed property

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    checklist: {
      types: [/* whatever */]
    }
  }),
  computed: {
    modules: ({ checklist: { types } }) => {
      const module1 = types.find(({ Name }) => Name === "Module1")
      return module1 ? [ module1 ] : types
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div v-for="module in modules" :key="module.Name">
  <span>{{ module.Name }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @MrMichael you should not paste it at all. You should attempt to understand what it is doing and incorporate the approach into your own code. Your CodeSandbox isn't helpful as it does not appear to contain any similarities to your question above